# Extracting digits of a real number with RealDigits produces unexpected result

Tags: number-representation, digits

I have a list of real numbers, each of which has two decimal places. I'm trying to extract the second digit after the decimal point.

The function I'm using is `RealDigits[num, 10, 1, -2]`.

It worked great for me until today when I noticed that for some numbers it produces the wrong result. For example the number `1370.12`:

```
RealDigits[1370.12, 10, 1, -2]
(* {{1}, -1} *)
```

I'd expect it to return `(*{{2}, -1}*)`.
Extracting other digits than the last one works well:

```
RealDigits[1370.12, 10, 1, #] & /@ {3, 2, 1, 0, -1, -2};
%[[All, 1]] // Flatten
(* {1, 3, 7, 0, 1, 1} *)
```

If I change the number `1370.12` say to `2370.12`, it gives the correct result for all digits

```
RealDigits[2370.12, 10, 1, #] & /@ {3, 2, 1, 0, -1, -2};
%[[All, 1]] // Flatten
(* {2, 3, 7, 0, 1, 2} *)
```

My question is why is the behavior like this? I assume it's how `RealDigits` works internally and is not a bug. How can I change my code to work correctly?

Comment: Use higher precision: ``RealDigits[1370.12`10, 10, 1, -2]`` or exact numbers ``RealDigits[Rationalize[1370.12], 10, 1, -2]``.

Comment: A very simplified explanation is that `RealDigits[]` is effectively starting from an internal binary representation. In particular, look at the result of `RealDigits[SetPrecision[1370.12, Infinity], 10, 1, -2]`.

Comment: The machine number that is displayed as "1370.12" is actually stored as an binary number :  10101011010.000111101. If we write this in decimal, we get:  1370.119999999999. As you can see, the digit -2 is really 1 and not 2.